# White spots on basil plant?

Tags: diseases, basil

My basil plant started getting some white spots a couple of weeks ago. I cut the leaves that had the white spots but the new leaves are growing again with the same white spots. Also, it's weird because I can't really see any bugs either on the top or the bottom of the leaf, so I am assuming that it is a fungus?

(also, it has been spreading among all my basil plants that are in different pots, but it doesn't seem to affect the tomatoes)

Thanks for your help!!

[image: My basil plant]

Comment: Is there anything odd underneath the leaves or are the marks just on the top? It looks a bit like thrips damage

Comment: That's the weird thing, that I can't really see anything odd like tiny black spots or tiny insects...